# Are Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ Theorem and the Monotone Class Theorem equivalent?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, set-theory

Let $X$ be a set. If $\mathcal{A}$ is a family of subsets of $X$ then let $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$.

*Definition $1$*

A **$\pi$-system on $X$** to be a non-empty family $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ closed under finite intersections (I wonder why such a fancy name).

*Definition $2$*

A **$\lambda$-system on $X$** is a family $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $X\in\mathcal{A}$ and that is closed under complements and unions of **pairwise disjoint** countable subfamilies.

*Definition $3$*

A **monotone class on $X$** is a family $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ that is closed unders unions and intersections of countable subfamilies of **nested** sets.

> **Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ Theorem** [(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_system#The_.CF.80-.CE.BB_Theorem)
>
> Let $\mathcal{I}$ be a $\pi$-system on $X$ and $\mathcal{D}$ be a $\lambda$-system on $X$. If $\mathcal{I}\subseteq \mathcal{D}$ then $\sigma(\mathcal{I})\subseteq \mathcal{D}$.

-

> **The Monotone Class Theorem** [(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem)
>
> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra of subsets of $X$ and suppose that $\mathcal{M}$ is the smallest monotone class on $X$ such that $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{M}$, then $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{M}$.

**My question:**

> I'd like to know if these two theorems are equivalent, in the sense of whether one can prove easily one from the other, in a way that makes it clear that for practical purposes they are to some extent interchangeable. More formally I would raise the question of whether they are equivalent given some "basic" set theory axioms (e.g. ZF).

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193970/monotone-class-theorem-vs-dynkin-pi-lambda-theorem) question seems to be asking the same thing but it's actually considering a different statement for the Monotone Class Theorem.