# $f\in L^1(0,1)$ Assume that $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)t^{2n}=0$ for all n=1,2,3... prove that $f=0$ a.e

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

$f\in L^1(0,1)$ Assume that $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)t^{2n}=0$ for all n=1,2,3...  prove that $f=0$ a.e

My work- I can prove this when $f\in C[0,1]$.

$\int f^2= \int|f||f|=\int|f||f-p+p|=\int|f||f-p|+|f||p|$.

I know how to proceed from here.

where P is of the form $p= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nt^{2n}$.

But my question is what happens when $f\in L^1(0,1)$. Can I still use a approximation theorem?

**Here is my work according to @Oliver Diaz.**

$A=\{f\in C[0,1]\ such\ that\ f(0)=0\}$ and $B=\operatorname{span}(x^{2n}, n=1,2,3..)$ we can prove ***$B$ is dense in $A$***.

Let us take $f\in A$ then consider, for each $\epsilon>0$ then there exists a $p\in B$ such that $\sup\{f-p\}\leq \epsilon$
$|\int_{0}^{1}f^2|=|\int_{0}^{1}f.f|=|\int_{0}^{1}f.(f-p+p)|\leq|\int_{0}^{1}f.(f-p)|+|\int f.p|=\int_{0}^{1}|f.(f-p)|+|\int f.p|$

here $|\int f.p|=0$ (from the assumption)

then $|\int_{0}^{1}f^2|\leq \int_{0}^{1}|f|.|(f-p)|\leq \int_{0}^{1} M.\epsilon=M.\epsilon $

And then, we can conclude that $f^2=0\ implies\ f=0.$

Now let's take $g\in L^1[0,1]$ , according to @Oliver's fact A is dense in $L^1 norm$.
what I need to show is that if

Here, Im kind of stuck. How do I prove your claim $$\int^1_0 g\mathbb{1}_{(a,b]}=0$$.

Comment: The space of polynomials in $t^2$ (no constant term ) is dense in the space of functions in $C([0,1])$ that banish at $0$(in the sup norm); this space is dense in $L_1{0,1]$. The first assertion is the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: The arguments outlined in (1) and (2) of my suggestion are not to conclude that  $\int f^2=0$. Though it follows as a logical conclusion once is established that $f=0$ $m$-a.s. it is not in the correct order of inferences. What one concludes from (1) and (2) is that for any bounded integrable function $g$, $\int fg=0$. Notice that $fg$ is integrable by virtue of $g$ being bounded. In particular, indicator functions of intervals may be used to deduce that $f=0$ $m$-a.s.

Comment: Hi ShanOH, I noticed that you have not edited the erroneous conclusion in your answer. Let me know if you still need some further clarification on the ideas. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This is a sketch of a proof. Try to fill in the missing details.

Let's denote by $m$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.

It is enough to assume that, besides being integrable, $f$ is Borel measurable (any Lebesgue measurable function is equal $m$-a.s. to a Borel measurable function).

1. The space of polynomials in $t^2$ with non zero constant term is dense in $A:=\{f\in C([0,1]): f(0)=0\}$ (uniform norm). This follows from the Stone-Werstrass theorem.
2. $A$ is dense in $L_1$, in particular, one can approximate any $\mathbb{1}_{(a,b]}$ by elements of $A$ (in the $L_1$-norm). From this, it follows that
   $$\int^1_0 f\mathbb{1}_{(a,b]}=0$$
   for all $0\leq a<b\leq 1$.
3. The conclusion then should be easy (monotone class arguments, [for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193970/monotone-class-theorem-vs-dynkin-pi-lambda-theorem)).

---

**Edit:** sketch of proof of (3): Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the collection of all Borel measurable sets $C$ in $[0,1]$ such that $\int_Cf=0$. As a result of parts (1) and (2),

- a. $\mathcal{D}$ contains the collection $\mathcal{C}$ of all  intervals $[a,b]\subset[0,1]$ (notice that if $\int_{(a,b]}f=0$, so is $\int_{[a,b]}f$, for the Lebesgue measure of $\{0\}$ is $0$.)
- b. $\mathcal{D}$ is a $\lambda$-system:

  b.1. $[0,1]\in D$ (obvious by (a));

  b.2. if $B,C\in \mathcal{D}$ and $B\subset C$, then $C\setminus B\in \mathcal{D}$ (the integrability of $f$ implies $\int_Cf-\int_Bf=\int_{C\setminus B}f$);

  b.3.  if $\{B_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset \mathcal{D}$ and $B_n\subset B_{n+1}$, then $\bigcup_nB_n\in\mathcal{D}$ (dominated convergence)
- c. $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\pi$-system, that is, is closed under intersections.
- d. By Dynkin's monotone class theorem $\sigma(\mathcal{C})\subset \mathcal{D}$. But since the  Borel $\sigma$-algebra, $\mathscr{B}([0,1])$, is generated by $\mathcal{C}$ ( i.e. $\mathcal{B}([0,1])=\sigma(\mathcal{C})$), we have that $\int_Bf=0$ for all $B\in\mathscr{B}([0,1])$.

**The punch line:** $\{f\neq0\}\in\mathscr{B}([0,1])$  and so, $\int_{\{f\neq0\}}f=0$. This implies that $m(\{f\neq0\})=0$, that is $f=0$ $m$-almost surely.

Comment: In fact the conclusion follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @copper.hat: Sure, once it has been established that $0=\int f\mathbb{1}_{(0,b]}$  for any $0<b\leq 1$, Lebesgue's fundamental theorem of calculus may also be used to obtain the desired conclusion.

Comment: Hello @OliverDiaz. I'm concerned about the fact that A is dense in $L_1$. I have seen continuous function are dense in $l_1$. but A is a specific set such that f(0)=0. are you going to neglect the point zero when it's comes to the integration?

Comment: Hello @OliverDiaz Thank you. I did a proof according to your points mentioned. It's in my question space with bolded letters. But I'm sorry I could not understand to use your fact about $$\int^1_0 f\mathbb{1}_{(a,b]}=0$$ Could you explain little more?

Comment: @ShanOH: Your conclusion that $f^2$ is integrable is false. I edited my answer to include the key points in the last step. I am using monotone class arguments, in particular [Dynkin's $\lambda-\pi$ theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system). This is a powerful tool in probability that has been also very useful in measure theory in general. As copper.hat mentioned in his comment, if you have Lebesgue's version of the fundamental theorem of Calculus, you can use that instead of Dynkin's theorem. My preference for the former is that is works also for more general (finite) measures.